# Custom UIControl and Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a custom UIControl similar to a slider.

This control is to be the subview of a view that also has a tap gesture recognizer attached to it.

The problem now is that this tap gesture recognizer cancels the touches sent to my control. Is there a way I can override this from within the code of my control?

If I look into the standard controls in iOS it looks as if UIButton has a way of overriding the tap gesture recognizer but UISlider doesn't. So if I replace my custom control with a UIButton the tap gesture recognizer does not trigger its action, but if I replace it with a slider it does.

**edit**: I made a small project in Xcode to play around in. Download here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/165243/TouchConcept.zip and try to change it so that

- The UICustomControl does not know about the tap gesture recognizer
- The UICustomControl is not cancelled when the user taps down on the yellow box
- The UICustomControl does not inherit from UIButton (that is a solution that does not feel right and might give me more headaches later on)

The code:

```
// inherit from UIButton will give the wanted behavior, inherit from UIView (or UIControl) gives
// touchesCancelled by the gesture recognizer
@interface UICustomControl : UIView

@end

@implementation UICustomControl

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   NSLog(@"touchesBegan"); }

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   NSLog(@"touchesMoved"); }

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   NSLog(@"touchesEnded"); }

-(void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   NSLog(@"touchesCancelled"); }

@end
@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(logTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    UIView *interceptingView = [[UICustomControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    interceptingView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    interceptingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview: interceptingView];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) logTap: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"gesture recognizer fired");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: When I overrode a UIControl I had to roll my own tracking by overriding UIResponder's touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Canceled:withEvent: and not calling super. I gave up using begin/continue/endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent: because it was problematic - too much stuff going on behind the scenes in there. HTH.

Comment: Sample project works fine: touchesBegan,Moved,Ended is not interfered with by gesture recogniser (hence you can track movement of your slider), but touch without moving gets swallowed by the tap recogniser. "to be the subview of a view that also has a tap gesture recognizer attached to it" implies EVERY tap in view must be recognised as a tap regardless of subviews, but that is plainly not what you want. Instead of using tap gesture recogniser, why not use touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Canceled:withEvent: in your view controller (=super in responder chain) to trap otherwise unhandled taps?

Comment: I verified again and for me (iPad simulator 6.1) it does NOT work as expected: the tap gesture recognizer fires every time, touchesCancelled is called every time and I never get touchesEnded. Your proposed solution is a workaround. At the moment I am going with another workaround: inheriting from UIButton.

Comment: 2013-09-04 10:20:27.287 TouchConcept[12033:c07] touchesBegan
2013-09-04 10:20:31.135 TouchConcept[12033:c07] touchesMoved
2013-09-04 10:20:31.184 TouchConcept[12033:c07] touchesMoved
2013-09-04 10:20:31.999 TouchConcept[12033:c07] touchesMoved
2013-09-04 10:20:32.959 TouchConcept[12033:c07] touchesMoved
2013-09-04 10:20:36.167 TouchConcept[12033:c07] touchesEnded

Comment: behaviour is flakey and unreliable: if you move and touch up quickly the GR fires, but if you move slowly and touch up slowly, it doesn't fire.

Comment: "Your proposed solution is a workaround." absolutely not. GR's are conceptually above the controls. If you want to catch taps that are left after controls have had their look in, you need to look underneath, i.e. further up the responder chain, i.e. take a look at what the view controller receives after other responders have consumed what they want.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure the gesture recognizer to *not* cancel touches in the view it's attached using the "cancels touches in view" property:

```
myGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Comment: I don't think that's a solution, as the gesture recognizer will still trigger its action. On top of that it requires changing the code in some superview of the control for the control to function properly.

Comment: @KristofVanLandschoot You can become the delegate for the two recognizers and have fine grained control over if they should recognize simultaneously or one should only recognize after the other has failed to.

Comment: Another day, another story, but it is the thing I missed

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little bit late, but for those (like me) stumbling into this question, I used an alternative solution:

**Use the delegate of the gesture recogniser.**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissInfoBox:)];
tapGestRec.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestRec];
```

Then do a sort of hit test in the *shouldReceiveTouch* delegate function when the gesture recogniser wants to handle/swallow a touch.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    return !CGRectContainsPoint(self.myCustomControl.frame, location) && !CGRectContainsPoint(self.myOtherCustomControl.frame, location);
}
```

I did all this in my ViewController, this way the UIControl does not have to know about any sibling views and the gesture recogniser does not 'steal' taps from my custom controls and only handles 'uncaught' taps.

Also, this way you won't trigger both the gesture recogniser *and* the custom control, which would happen with *cancelsTouchesInView*.

BTW, maybe it works with UIButton because UIButton uses gesture recognisers internally? I think they understand each other, while UIControls and recognisers do not. Not sure though.

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get it to work. The gesture recognizer delegate method is only called when touches fall within the **subview** associated with the gesture anyway. My setup has a label with a tap gesture and my custom control as both subviews of the main view.

Comment: Oh, wait, there was an additional tap gesture attached to the whole view. I should target that one

Answer (score 5):

override `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)` in your `UIControl` subclass.

```
    public override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UITapGestureRecognizer.self) {
            return false
        } else {
            return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should follow this tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view

It shows you How to make a custom uiview.

And then do follow this one
http://www.raywenderlich.com/29474/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-custom-input-view-tutorial

Comment: That is too general to accept as an answer, sorry :) Thanks for the links though, I'll take a look at them and see if the answer to my question is somewhere in there.